# Drawing a bounding box around each line of a driver's license

Tags: node.js, opencv, ocr, tesseract

I'm trying to prepare a license driver card for `OCR`. First I want to detect each line of the card because when I use `tesseract` `OCR` I don't get useful text on the card( I get each word in a newline and unordered) I want to get the text line by line to make it easier for me to extract like license number, first name, place of issue etc...
So I found a solution to use `OpenCV` to cut each line of the card and save it as separate image and read the text of each image so I could do  some regex operation to extract the number or first name,
but the code isn't working perfectly. It doesn't find the line of the card perfectly.

here is my code using opencv4nodejs :

```
const cv = require('opencv4nodejs');
const img = cv.imread('license_driver.jpg');
const grayImg = img.bgrToGray();
const thresholdImg = grayImg.threshold(50, 255, cv.THRESH_BINARY | cv.THRESH_OTSU);
const kernel = cv.getStructuringElement(cv.MORPH_RECT, new cv.Size(4, 10));
const morphedImg = thresholdImg.morphologyEx(kernel, cv.MORPH_RECT);
const filteredImg = morphedImg.gaussianBlur(new cv.Size(5, 5), 0);
cv.imwrite('output2.jpg', filteredImg);
const contours = filteredImg.findContours(cv.RETR_LIST, cv.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE);
const textLineContours = contours.filter(contour => 
{
   const { x, y, width, height } = contour.boundingRect();
   const aspectRatio = width / height;
   const area = contour.area;
   return aspectRatio > 0.1 && area > 100 && area < 50000;
});
for (let i = 0; i < textLineContours.length; i++) 
{
   const rect = textLineContours[i].boundingRect();
   img.drawRectangle(rect, new cv.Vec(0, 255, 0), 2);
}
cv.imwrite('output.jpg', img);
```

Here is the input image:

[image: here is the input image]

Here is the output image:

[image: here is the output image]

I want my desired output to be like this:

[image: I want my desired output to be like this]